# multiple div using the same class open at once

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I am using the javascript function for multiple hide show divs in custom tumblr theme.. my The problem is as the class name is same, if i click on a single div, by default all the div gets show or hide.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".toggleme").click(function () {
    $(".toparea3").slideToggle("slow");
  return false;
   });
    });
</script>

<a class="toggleme" href="#"><img src="http://www.abc.com/images/share.png"></a>

<div class="toparea3" style="display:none;">
    <div class="share-bar clearfix" style=" margin-top:3px;margin-left: -2px;width: 380px;height: 50px;">
        <div class="share-bar-buttons">
            <div class="share-bar-facebook">
                <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={URLEncodedPermalink}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=110&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:80px;margin-top: 15px;" class="share-bar-twitter">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
                                      data-url="{Permalink}" 
                                      {block:Twitter}data-via="{TwitterUsername}"{/block:Twitter} 
                                      data-related="stylehatch:Premium Tumblr Themes by @newezra"></a>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right;margin-top:-25px;" class="share-bar-shorturl">
            <div class="linktumb">
                http://www.tumblr.com/xdrs2sf
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

Place the 'a' and the corresponding 'div' in a parent 'div'. Something like this:

```
<div>
    <a class='toggleMe' />
    <div class='toparea3 />
</div>
```

Then you can update your inner selector to be:

```
$('.toggleMe').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    $(".toparea3", parent).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple "toggleme" buttons, if they're all in the format where you have a toggleme button and then a toparea3, you could do something like this:

```
$('.toggleme').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

The "next" function gets the next element in the DOM, which is the element you want to expand.

Comment: http://ceescripts.tumblr.com/
this is the link, when you click on share this button, all the div gets show/hide

Comment: Well, that's because you use Chad's idea, and you gave them all the same hash. Each one is supposed to have a different hash corresponding to the div you want to open.

Comment: i can not have a different css id as the toparea3 div is iterated by tumblr

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** (nevermind the .children)

try using the .closest selector, or the .next selector someone else suggested. Just remember to provide the selector `.toparea3` to make sure that only that class opens, not just any closest/next element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggleme").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".toparea3").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the toparea divs are children of the toggleme links.

Comment: Here you go, a fiddle. My `.closest` idea didn't work. But Will's `.next` idea did.
http://jsfiddle.net/8ALaU/

Answer (score 0):

My Recommendation is to give the div an id, and make the anchor element's `href` point to it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggleme").click(function () {
        $(this.hash).slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<a class="toggleme" href="#toparea3_1"><img src="http://www.abc.com/images/share.png"></a>

<div id="toparea3_1" class="toparea3" style="display:none;"></div>
```

This since the hash is given in the form `#toparea3_1` that is a valid jQuery selector that selects on ID, and can be used directly.